# list of brackets, Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

The task is describe infinite list (called brackets) of strings
Example of such list: `["[]", "[[]]", "[[[]]]", "[[[[]]]]"...]`

If I'll write `take 4 brackets` the result should be
`["[]","[[]]","[[[]]]","[[[[]]]]"]`.

In this task I should use a trick called "tying the knot".
It is something like that:

```
geom= 1 : map (/2) geom
```

---

My solution is

```
brackets = "[]": map (\xs -> "[" + xs + "]" ) brackets
```

but I got error:

```
Unresolved top-level overloading
*** Binding             : brackets
*** Outstanding context : Num [Char]
```

Answer (score 4):

`(+)` is an operator for adding together numbers, not concatenating lists/strings. Try `(++)` for that.